# Deactivating DoubleClick via Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, double-click-advertising

I am working on a task to block certain trackers and cookies based on user selection for GDPR purposes. The trackers are set into 3 categories, Essential, Advertising and Marketing. We treat Google Analytics and Essential and Google DoubleClick as Advertising. However it seems I can't disable DoubleClick this way as it is a part of GA and is triggered every time GA is activated. We eventually decided to just disable DoubleClick as we are not using it but all guides tell me to log into GA, go to Admin > Property > Tracking Info > Data Collection and disable the Remarketing option (even the official GA documentation) but we do not have this option. We only have Data Collection for Google signals and Advanced Settings to Allow Ads Personalization, both of which I have disabled and DoubleClick still doesn't seem to be deactivated.

Can someone help me figure out how to disable DoubleClick in GA?

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable Demographics features, however, if you have activated **Google signals**, the controls to enable Demographics and Interests reports are not available: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7532985

Anyway you can disable it programmatically, i.e. with `gtag`:

```
gtag('set', 'allow_ad_personalization_signals', false);
```

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9050852?hl=en

You can fine more info on **how doubleclick cookie works** here: https://www.analyticstraps.com/gdpr-e-cookie-di-doubleclick/

Comment: Just to keep this answer up to date. The gtag code approach no longer works (as of July 2020), it can only be changed via the GA interface: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9050852?hl=en